# Swift textview text show dots instead of text

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a text view next to a button. When the user taps the button I want the text which I want to start off as  ••••••••. Nothing is working right. First off the text shows up as regular text not the dots...and therefore when i tap the button it does not doing anything since it is already in the state..

heres my code

in the viewdidload

```
passwordToReveal.text = "Testing"
passwordToReveal.secureTextEntry = true



func revealPassword(){

    passwordToReveal.secureTextEntry = false



    delay(5.0) { 
        self.hidePassword()
    }
}

func hidePassword(){
    passwordToReveal.secureTextEntry = true

}



func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

@IBAction func revealPassword(sender: UIButton) {

    revealPassword()

}
```

Comment: your code is fine. You probably facked up somewhere else

Comment: i added the delegates and everything but its not working :/

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2k3dvv8zdhp019u/securityField.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thx, i was using a textView instead of a textField